# Java TCP IP connection - nothing appears at server

Tags: java, tcp

I use this Thread at server side in order to receive Strings from client:

```
int clientNumber = 0;
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(6543);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
...

private static class Capitalizer extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private int clientNumber;

    public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (true) {
                String input = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Am Server: " + input);
                out.println(input.toUpperCase());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And the client looks like this:

```
try {
        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 6543);
        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter something : ");
            String input = br.readLine();
            out.write(input.getBytes());
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is not clear for me that at server side no string is received. 
I enter a string in Eclipse console and at client this string is sent to server but at server side nothing happens. 
Does anyone have a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: BTW: you should avoid input.getBytes() as it is not a international capable API, better use getBytes(StandardEncodings.UTF8) or similar.

Comment: readLine() reads lines (bytes terminated by a new line character) and you are not writing any. I suggest you not mix text e.g. Reader/Writer and binary e.g. InputStrea/OutputStream and only use one (most likely text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server expects to receive *lines*, so your client must send lines. But your client does not send lines. Why?

From the [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_readline.htm):

> Return Value
>   A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.

Thus the return value of `readline` is *not* a line since, as that same page says:

> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

To avoid this mistake in the future, before you use TCP, specify *in writing* precisely what information will be sent and received. If you're using TCP to exchange messages, defined *precisely* what a message is -- at the byte level.

For this application, you should have precisely specified that the messages will consist of a sequence of characters not including any line terminator characters whose end is marked with a line ending. That would have made it clear that the client was buggy, since it's obviously not sending messages as specified by the protocol.